# JavaScript - The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: angularjs, video

I made a website where if the user clicks, it should plays a video. and clicking on same should pause,

whenever I tried to pause it is showing

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().
```

here is my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eLcV7n3AuBqKYYUqalfR)

Can someone assist me?

I tried

```
setTimeout(function () {  
var item = $(".myVideosClick")[0];          
  if (!item.paused) {
    item.pause();
  }
}, 100);
```

but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `setTimeout` use `$timeout` service which is the Angular wrapper for `setTimeout` and it uses `$scope.$apply` inside.
Also, instead of using `JQuery` for `click` event binding use `ng-click` directive. Example:

```
$scope.videoClickHandler = function(){
    //do on click logic
}
```

Also you can try to make bigger timeout, 300 works well in my case.

Comment: check this plnkr @Ihor, same issue https://plnkr.co/edit/6Oq1SdOT8RWhKf3AWu8A?p=catalogue

Comment: to understand for Javascript developers I did that, but usually we follow what you said, Thanks

Comment: @satishkumarV I have no errors in console of the updated plnkr

Comment: that I fixed, Thanks :) @Ihor